# i am trying to scrape this website with scrapy python. I scraped most of the information but for some reason xpath doesnot scrape a division

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

[Page i am trying to scrape](https://www.maisonsdumonde.com/UK/en/p/scandinavian-3-seater-light-grey-sofa-brooke-166156.htm)

this is my code

```
 Download_links = response.xpath('//div[@class = "download-block"]').extract()
```

this returns a empy list. Why cannot i scrape this div only?

This is the part of page i am trying to scrape
[photo for the part i am trying to scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erWF4.png)

Please provide some help

Comment: If you look at the page source (literally the page source - not the DOM shown in the browser's dev tools) - do you see anything using that class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an empty list because the division is not in the page source. Always check whether the data exists in the page source before writing xpaths.
The data may be in some other part of the page, please search the page source (ctrl+u) and get the correct xpath for the same.
Here in this page the download links are there in the pagesource.
[see the image of the page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRcMN.png)